# Split array in array of array with LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I would like to split my array that consists of objects in arrays, grouping them by some property of the type (let's say

```
string Group {get; set;}
```

).

At the beginning I have

```
IEnumerable<T> array.
```

Then I would like to get

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> array.
```

Of course, I can do it without LINQ, but it will look too ugly and verbose.

Comment: *"Of course, I can do it without LINQ, but it will look too ugly"*, why don't you show us how ugly that might look? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.GroupBy(item => item.Group)
```

this will give you `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, YourType>>`. The  `IGrouping<string, YourType>` extends `IEnumerble<YourType>` with `Key`, which will be the value of `Group` property in your example:

```
foreach (var g in array.GroupBy(item => item.Group))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group='{0}', {1} items", g.Key, g.Count());
}
```

Comment: beautiful solution.Thanks !